# gestureRecognizerShouldBegin blocks the collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`on a `collectionViewCell`

```
let swipeToRight = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))
 swipeToRight.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
 swipeToRight.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
 swipeToRight.delegate = self
 container.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToRight)
```

but it interrupts scrolling, so I use `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` to let me scrolling as well.

```
   public override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if let pan = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let velocity = pan.velocity(in: self)
        return abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y)
    }
    return true
}
```

And it works well, but as you can see in the screenshot from the view hierarchy, for some random cell, it added a gesture recognizer in the top of the `collectionViewCell`and it blockes every button on the cell. I printed the view description from the view hierarchy.

```
Printing description of $33:
<UIView: 0x10b678d30; frame = (0 0; 410 357.667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280800660>; layer = <CALayer: 0x280484ce0>>
```

if I use `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`, I will have exactly the same problem

```
  public override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if let pan = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let velocity = pan.velocity(in: self)
        return abs(velocity.x) > abs(velocity.y)
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: the screenshot from the view hierarchy]

And for example, here is the screenshot from the view hierarchy for an another cell that works as expected and there is no any blocking view

[image]

I have been stuck with this issue in the past few days, could anyone help me that how I can fix it? I even competently remove my `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` still makes that issue for some random cell.
Your help will be so highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention the issue occurs only in a few cells and not in others, I'm assuming this has something to do with how the views within the cell are being added as subviews.

I would recommend you check if you are adding your views within the [`contentView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview) of the UICollectionViewCell instance instead of adding views directly into the cell **which is not recommended**. This could be one reason for this issue although, given the details, I can't say for sure.

If the above is not it, please attach an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue so I'm able to look into this with more detail and context.